# PrimeNg tree: how to get a list of all selected items

Tags: angular, primeng

I have written custom code to get the list of all selected nodes in a tree. Essentially I book keep that inside the onSelect function.

Is there a tree API that I use to eliminate my custom code?

Comment: Did you try adding `[(selection)]="selectedItems"` to your `<p-tree>` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to manually keep track of the selected nodes using the `onSelect` event handler.
If you add `[(selection)]="selectedItems"` like below, the `value` property of the selected nodes should be stored in the `selectedItems` variable as an array.

`<p-tree selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedItems"></p-tree>`

Note: This will be the list of the `value` property of the selected nodes and not the nodes themselves. You will have to iterate manually if you need the nodes.

Comment: How do you iterate through the nodes?  I'm trying to find all top-level nodes and their selected children's values